# Spring + Hibernate: Session management within @Transactional methods

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

There's a lot of questions here on this topic, but still I'm not clear with the procedure of managing session within the transaction.

Let's assume there's some repo:

```
@Repository
public class SomeRepository {
    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public void doSomething() throws IOException {
        Session session = getSession();
        List<SomeEntity> someEntities = session.createCriteria(SomeEntity.class).list();
        for (int i = index; i < someEntities.size(); i++) {
            /* Some ops with entities */
            if (i % 100 == 0) {
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
            }
        }
        session.close;
    }

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

Is this code correct? Do I really need to open and close (and flush and clear) session manually each time the operation is running? May I use `getCurrentSession()` instead and forget about flushing and closing (cuz I guess transaction may take care about the lifecycle for me)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not correct. To get the session associated with the current Spring transaction, you must use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.

And you should never close the session: that's the job of Spring, which will close it when the transaction commits/rollbacks, or even later in the open-session-in-view pattern is used.

Flushing is generally not necessary, except in the situation described in the Hibernate documentation, and which consists in avoiding increasing the size of the first-level cache when you insert a large number of entities in batch. In your case, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Use them when it makes sense using them. in 99% of the cases, they're not useful. But that doesn't have anything to do with Spring and transactions. it just depends on the particular use-case.

Comment: Wait... Forgot about multithreading... What if I have to access session in many Java threads? Is there something different in it's lifecycle?

Comment: Each thread will have its own transaction, and its own current session. You can't share a transaction and a session between threads. As soon as you start a thread, the code executing in the thread is not part of the current transaction anymore.

Comment: "Each thread will have its own transaction" - it's when I call Transactional method within a Runnable class, right? And what if I do opposite thing: create new thread within the Transactional method and pass the session to Runnable via final parameter?

Comment: Don't do that. Session are not thread-safe, and can't be shared between threads. And the Spring transaction context will not be propagated to the new thread either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35784/discussion-between-dmytro-titov-and-jb-nizet)

Comment: @JBNizet Just a point there can be multiple session with in a thread with different propagation behavior like with `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`